# How do I load CPS Global Lib from the specified branch instead of master?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I am studying Jenkins Pipeline [Global Lib](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/tree/master/cps-global-lib) functionality. It seems pretty handy however due to its global nature any harmful change will affect all the jobs. Thus I want to be able to test it before pushing to master on a different branch.

Is there a way to specify a branch from which I want to to include the global lib sources for a particular job?

**UPDATE.** I tried a workaround with direct `git clone` from the test branch then `load` my library file explicitly replacing the automatically loaded one.
The problem comes when this lib uses some other class from the `src/`. Because in this case its pre-loaded version from master is always used.

So in the conditions below it runs common.groovy from **feature-test** but prints `Hello from master!!!!` when `b.dummy()` is called.

**Pipeline Script in Jenkins:**

```
node('myhost'){
    git url: 'ssh://10.0.0.1:12345/workflowLibs.git',
        branch: 'feature-test'

    dir ('src'){
        load 'com/foo/Base.groovy'
    }
    dir ('vars'){
        common = load 'common.groovy'
    }
}

println common.dummy()
```

**vars/common.groovy (feature-test):**

```
package com.foo
def dummy(){
    def b = new com.foo.Base()
    b.dummy()
}
```

**src/com/foo/Base.groovy (master):**

```
package com.foo
def dummy(){
    return 'Hello from master!!!!'
}
```

**src/com/foo/Base.groovy (feature-test):**

```
package com.foo
def dummy(){
    return 'Hello from feature-test!!!!'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm aware, this isn't possible — scripts pushed to this repo can't be versioned by having different branches.

There are a few alternative approaches you could take, which involve hosting your scripts in an external repo (i.e. not with the Global Lib repo):

---

You could use the [Pipeline Remote Loader plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Remote+Loader+Plugin), which allows you to pull Pipeline scripts from a remote repo, e.g.

```
def p = fileLoader.fromGit('bar/common.groovy', 
          'https://example.com/foo/pipelines.git',
          'test-branch', null, '')
p.doSomething()
```

You can also use this plugin to easily load multiple Pipeline scripts from the same repo.

---

Alternatively, you could check out your script Git repo within a Pipeline execution and `load` a script directly:

```
stage 'Load scripts'
def p
dir('tmp') {
    git url: 'https://example.com/foo/pipelines.git',
        branch: 'test-branch'
    p = load 'bar/common.groovy'
}

stage 'Do something'
p.doSomething()
```

---

If you want to keep on using the Global Lib repo, you could use the above techniques for testing the scripts, and then set up a Jenkins job to push your script changes into the master Global Lib repo.

Comment: Work is planned on bringing together the best features of Global Lib and Remote Loader, but for now these are your options.

Comment: Looks cool, thanks! However I didn't get if there is any diiference except convenient interface from git+load? Any difference in the load procedure?

Comment: BTW, is there a way to bring some remote directories into the current script's classpath, at least for the loading phase? Say I have two library groovy scripts that shares some code. How can I include this common part within that scripts? Plain `import` can't locate the files. I tried manipulating with current classpath via `this.class.classLoader.rootLoader` but it's `null`.

Comment: I created a separate question instead http://stackoverflow.com/q/35637833/1579623

Comment: Global Pipeline Library now supports specifying version, https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin/blob/master/README.md, and is by far more convenient that Pipeline Remote Loader.